# System Object Method issue

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have only today learned about the FSO so I am trying to implement it in to my database so import stats hourly (a new file appears in a folder hourly)

When I run the code it finds the file but does not import the data and throws out a runtime 3011 error

My Module code:

```
  Function getFilename(path As String) As String
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim dateModified As Date

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(path)

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
Debug.Print objFile.Name
If InStr(objFile.Name, "hourly performance") > 0 And Not Left(objFile.Name, 1) = "~" Then
    If objFile.datelastmodified > dateModified Then
    dateModified = objFile.datelastmodified
    getFilename = objFile.Name
    End If

End If

Next objFile

End Function
```

My VBA code is then:

```
 Dim strFilename As String

strFilename = getFilename("C:\stats folder hourly\")

' Import Weekly stats
            DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet transfertype:=acImport, SpreadsheetType:=10, _
            tablename:="Weekly", FileName:=strFilename, _
            Hasfieldnames:=True, Range:="AgentActivity CSV!"
```

The error:

> Microsoft access database engine could not find the object 'FILENAME' Make sure the object exists and that you spell the name and the path name correctly

Help

Comment: your `getFilename()` function will return either a blank string `""` or a _simple_ file name (with no path). A for the first issue you should add a check `If strFilename  <> "" Then  DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet ...` As for the second issue does `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` need `strFilename` as a _pure_ name or does it need with fullpath? And finally does it need that file to be opened ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem

```
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet transfertype:=acImport, SpreadsheetType:=10, _
    tablename:="Hourly", FileName:="FILPATH" & hourly & "", _
    Hasfieldnames:=True, Range:="AgentActivity CSV!"
```

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
getFilename = objFile.Name
```

to

```
getFilename = objFSO.GetAbsolutePathName(objFile)
```

wich will give you absolute path like c:\folder\file.ext